# sqlite unclosed read transaction

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, multithreading, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 in an iOS application and I've encountered a very strange issue multiple 
times.

I'm using WAL and all of my writes happen on a managed thread that only allows 1 operation at a time and my reads use a different database handle and everything works fine.  The issue I'm seeing is sometimes my read handle gets into this weird state where it won't read committed data.  It's like it has an uncommitted read transaction...

I can write successfully to the database and I've exported my results to my computer where I see the newly written results just fine.  However, my reads seem to access the database at an older point in time...it's like they're stuck.  If I close the application and reopen it, they're fine and they read the newly committed data, but I'm wondering how my application is getting stuck in this state.

ANY help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do other write transactions succeed in this state?

Comment: Yes. My writes use a different database handle and if I write, then export the database, I see they go through successfully.

Comment: The weird thing is the new data isn't read...my reads still access old data.

Comment: What does [`PRAGMA compile_options`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_compile_options) return? Are you using [`sqlite3_config`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/config.html), or shared cache mode?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same issue but on Debian Lenny (kernel 2.6.33) w/ SQLite3 3.7.7.1.

It turned out that I got some processes hanging on to some stale DB file descriptors after I deleted and recreated a database file.

I fixed it by making sure all processes that used the DB were killed before recreating the DB again.

By getting rid of the old processes, the file handles were deleted as well.